# _findfirst and WinRT access denied

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I am porting existing C++ app (game engine) to support Windows Store 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 Apps and I am having problem with the _wfindfirst function. On regular Win32 it returns a handle to the first found element matching the pattern. we use it mainly to get information about directory or file.

The function I am trying to get working on WindowsPhone/Windows Store App is like this:

```
bool sys_GetFileInfo(const std::string& path, FileInfo* info) {
  ...
  long handle = _wfindfirst(p.c_str(), &item); // path gets converted to wstring
  if (handle != -1L) {
    info->size = (item.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) ? -1 : item.size;
    info->modifiedAt = item.time_write;
    _findclose(handle);
    return true;
  }
  ...
}
```

So it was used to retrieve file size and modification date (and if it happened to be directory the size was set to -1)

The first usage was to get info about working directory of an exe so in case of the WinRT/WP/WS I am using it with the path provided by

```
std::wstring wpath = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path->Data();
```

The path in this case is:

```
 wpath = L"C:\\foo\\winrt\\winrt\\Debug\\foo_winrt.Windows\\AppX"
```

The problem is that it always returns -1, when I check the error string with GetLastError() code I get the access denied error. This is confusing as in my understanding application should have read access to this location so _wfindfirst is a read operation right? On Win32 it worked given a regular directory path.

Why this function fails? Is there any other viable option to achieve the same result for WinRT ?

Answer (score 0):

If still relevant, it seems you are not able to use standard C++ functions to access file system outside your app's sandbox (installed location and local app folder). They will fail with Access denied error. I think they behave pretty much the way [CreateFile2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422) behaves, and according to MSDN:

> When called from a Windows Store app, CreateFile2 is simplified. You can open only files or directories inside the ApplicationData.LocalFolder or Package.InstalledLocation directories.

In your case, as I can see, the installed location points to a development folder, and I think the system decides that this location isn't inside your app's sandbox.

Consider using **Windows Runtime APIs** from Windows.Storage namespace. These APIs can be used to access any file in the file system.